# Hacer un uso correcto de las etiquetas tanto en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, web

Mejor forma de aprender a estructurar bien un código html y conocer si una etiqueta va dentro de otra. No sé cómo saber si un article va dentro de un div o un section por ejemplo y al final acabo realizando un código muy extenso sin saber si he utilizado las etiquetas correctas. Por consiguiente en CSS a la hora de modificar las etiquetas se aplican los cambios a otras etiquetas y quisiera conocer algún método para poder tener un código más estructurado y saber exactamente qué voy a modificar cuando aplique estilos.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se ajusta al formato de [ask] por ende terminaría cerrada, te sugiero además hagas el [tour]. Finalmente [este recurso te puede ayudar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas buscar es información en temas como "accesibilidad" o "HTML semántico". Aquí te dejo una documentación muy útil en español que trata del buen uso de los tags:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML

En regla general, piensa en lo siguiente: **los elementos de tu página se debe identificar sin una hoja CSS**, utiliza los estilos nativos por convención para construir tu estructura.

Esto es super importante, ya que el único interés que tienen las buenas prácticas semánticas en HTML es la accesibilidad. Accesibilidad significa que personas discapacitadas puedan acceder a la información lo más naturalmente posible, que un lector de página para no videntes entienda cuál es tu encabezado, tus títulos, subtítulos etc. Igualmente, para el SEO, que los robots entiendan e indexen tu información para poder distribuirla.

Comment: debe de ser fundamental y una buena práctica el utilizar correctamente las etiquetas entiendo también que me puede servir la web de W3 para comprobar si la web está correctamente.

Comment: Exacto, sin embargo, solo tú, humano, puede entender que un título es el título, un comentario, es un comentario, etc. Depende de ti y tu criterio indicar al sistema qué define cada tag en tu estructura, ya que insisto, la correcta estructura debe seguir principios de accesibilidad. Ahora tu CSS es solo para pintar y, muy entre comillas, "no hay reglas". Es super interesante el tema del esqueleto HTML y el buen uso de tags como aside, main, pre, article, section, header, etc... Siempre piensa en accesibilidad y encontrarás el camino correcto. Buen aprendizaje!

Comment: Hay varias consideraciones a tener en cuenta: la primera es la estructura (habitualmente bajo la categoría «HTML semántico»), la segunda que todos los clientes (navegadores, lectores para personas no videntes, teclados para personas con dificultades de movilidad, pero sobre todo buscadores —que solo ven el código) puedan ver todos los elementos relevantes y entender la página. Si no tienes problemas con el inglés, sitepoint.com, smashingmagazine.com y alistapart.com son muy buenas referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es muy general por lo que voy  a tratar de guiarte los mejor posible.
Para el uso correcto de etiquetas y el anidamiento de las mismas dentro de otras lo primero que te recomiendo es que previo al código realices un diseño y estructura de como quieres que se vea tu web. Un dibujo de donde piensas ubicar cada elemento, por ejemplo el menu de navegación, footer, parte principal, aside si lo tuviese. Luego de esto vas a estructurar las partes de cada una de estas partes. Se suelen usar dibujos en forma de árboles.
Luego para saber que etiqueta usar para cada contenido de tu web te recomiendo que revises la documentación sobre html 5 de la w3c, w3school o developer mozilla.
Para aplicar cambios en css solo a las etiquetas que quieres prueba asignandoles clases o id o selectores específicos.

Te escribo ejemplos en código:

```
html:
<nav id="menu_principal">
    <ul>
        <li class="elemento_menu"><a href="">INICIO</a></li>
        <li class="elemento_menu"><a href="">CONOCENOS</a></li>
        <li class="elemento_menu"><a href="">CONTACTO</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:
para cambiar los estilos del nav podes usar

```
#menu_principal{
               /* acá van tus estilos*/
}

/* usas # para hacer referencia a un selector de tipo id*/
```

y en el caso de los li

```
.elemento_menu {
               /* acá van tus estilos*/  
}

/*aca usas . porque estas usando un selector de clase*/
```

Se puede dar la misma clase a varios elementos, los id se recomiendan usarlos para elementos únicos.

Hay más maneras de seleccionar, te recomiendo buscar sobre selectores en css en algún video que este explicado de manera más didáctica que en este texto.

Espero haberte ayudado!!!

Comment: A la hora de realizar el "esquelto" del html por ejemplo en el caso que me indicas del "menú principal "no podría ir dentro de un div? Cuándo debo de introducir una etiqueta dentro de otra y si dentro del menú introduzco un H1? Este debe de ir dentro de otra etiqueta por ejemplo o puede ir justo debajo del </ul> y antes del </nav>?  No sé si me explico bien quizá es algo confuso gracias de todas maneras pro la ayuda.

Comment: Por lo general la barra de navegación principal va dentro de tu header. No obstante muchas web poseen barras de navegación "sociales", donde se colocan iconos que son enlaces a las redes sociales. En este caso el nav puede ir dentro de un div. En el caso del H1 que me consultas debería revisar que dice la documentación y las especificaciones para SEO, ya que la etiqueta H1 es muy relevante para los motores de búsqueda.

Comment: Revisaré la documentación a través de developerMozilla y comprobaré el código a través de w3, crees que es aconsejable que me haga plantillas para cuando empiece un proyecto tener ya el menú realizado o es mejor que siempre empiece la web de 0 para ir practicando